# Implementing end-to-end encryption with user-controlled decryption for data transmitted between a ReactJS frontend and PHP backend

Tags: php, reactjs, encryption, cryptography, reverse-proxy

### Problem Description

I am developing a web application using ReactJS on the frontend and PHP on the backend. I need to implement a secure mechanism where users can transmit sensitive data to the server, but only they can decrypt and access the data.

### Requirements

Here are the requirements:

- The data should be encrypted on the client-side using a cryptographic library in ReactJS and remain encrypted until it reaches the user.
- The server or the admin of the database should not have access to the user's decrypted data.
- Users should be able to access their data from different devices while maintaining the decryption control.

I have considered using asymmetric encryption with a key pair, but that doesn't satisfy the requirement of user-controlled decryption since the server needs access to the private key to decrypt the data.

One approach I am considering is using a reverse proxy to handle the encryption and decryption on behalf of the user. However, I am unsure about the best practices and implementation details for this approach.

Specifically, I would appreciate guidance on the following:

1. How can I use a cryptographic library in ReactJS to securely encrypt the data on the client-side?
2. How can I ensure that the server or the admin of the database cannot access the user's decrypted data?
3. What are the best practices for implementing a reverse proxy to handle encryption and decryption on behalf of the user?
4. Are there any alternative approaches or cryptographic libraries in ReactJS that could better suit my requirements?

Any suggestions, guidance, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

### What have I tried already?

- Reverse proxy with accessing over OpenAPI private and public key of the user and encrypt/decrypt the data on the fly - seems to be quite unsecure because of using the keys on the reverse proxy side
- crypto-js for ReactJS app - it's slows down the page loading especially when the big chunk of data has been transffered - and additionally keys has to be somehow shared between devices, not quite sure how to solve that without some OpenAPI service, but then it has no sense as my server will keep the data and the keys
- The user is required to create a simple, memorable password during the login process. Once the password is entered, the browser securely stores it on the client-side. When the user logs in from another browser, it can enter the memorable password again, which will be used to encrypt and decrypt data retrieved from the database.

Comment: Essentially, if the server must not be able to decrypt the data, the data is to be encrypted and decrypted in the browser, and the user only accesses their own data: just let the user enter their password and use it (or a derivative of it) to en-/decrypt data in the browser…!?

Comment: @deceze that's something  that  came to my mind already, but it also brings a problem what to do when the user forget the password, there is no easy way to reverse it or allow the user to protect the data against lost

Comment: Yeah, if they're keeping their data *that* close to their chest, then they also really need to guard the only key that'll let them access it.